# Add Same Product with different sizes and prices to the cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reduce, shopping-cart

I can add different products as individual arrays and I can also increase and decrease the quantities if the same product added. But I would want to add same product with different size. Below is my code.. Please help out..!

Context screen:

```
 const initialState = {
  
  products: ProductData,
    cart: [],
  };
 
const reducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD':
            const item = state.products.find(
                (product) => product.id === action.payload.id
              );
              // Check if Item is in cart already
              const inCart = state.cart.find((item) =>
                item.id === action.payload.id ? true : false
              );
        
              return {
                ...state,
                cart: inCart
                  ? state.cart.map((item) =>
                      item.id === action.payload.id
                        ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 }
                        : item
                    )
                  : [...state.cart, { ...item, qty: 1 }],
              };
            
        case 'DELETE':
        return {
            ...state,
            cart: state.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id),
          };
       
        case 'INCREASE':
               const tempCart = state.cart.map((cartItem) => {
                if (cartItem.id === action.payLoad.id) {
                  return { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty + 1 };
                }
                return cartItem;
              });
              return { ...state, cart: tempCart };
        
        case 'DECREASE':
                const temp = state.cart.map((cartItem) => {
                    if (cartItem.id === action.payLoad.id) {
                      return { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty - 1 };
                    }
                 return cartItem;
                  })
                  .filter((cartItem) => cartItem.qty !== 0);
                return { ...state, cart: temp };
              
        case 'CLEAR':
              return {cart :[]}
           
        default:
            throw new Error(`unknow action.${action.type}`)
    }

}
```

Product Data

```
 export const ProductData = [
{
  id: 'C1',
  name:'Coffee',
  categories: [1],
  price: 15.00,
  prices: [
    {size: 'S', price: '1.38', currency: '$'},
    {size: 'M', price: '3.15', currency: '$'},
    {size: 'L', price: '4.29', currency: '$'},
  ],
 
{
  id: 'C2',
  name: "Coffee",
  icon:icons.coffee_1,
  categories: [1,2],
  price: 15.00,
  prices: [
    {size: 'S', price: '1.38', currency: '$'},
    {size: 'M', price: '3.15', currency: '$'},
    {size: 'L', price: '4.29', currency: '$'},
  ],
```

}
]

I can add, delete, increase and decrease  but I wanna add same product to the cart with different specification. your help is highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your action.payload from {id:''} to {id:'',size:''}.

```
case 'ADD':
  const newItem = { ...action.payload, qty: 1 };
  const existingItemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(
    (item) => item.id === action.payload.id && item.size === action.payload.size
  );

  if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
    // Product with the same specifications is already in the cart, increment quantity
    const updatedCart = state.cart.map((item, index) =>
      index === existingItemIndex ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 } : item
    );

    return { ...state, cart: updatedCart };
  } else {
    // Product with different specifications or not in the cart, add a new item
    return { ...state, cart: [...state.cart, newItem] };
  }
```

Comment: Well, Your code is working and thank you for that, But can you please show me how to display each product in the cart screen after adding with different selected size? here is my cart screen code `const Cart=({navigation})=>{    const {cart}= useCart();    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = React.useState(0);  const [totalItems, setTotalItems] = React.useState(0);  React.useEffect(() => {  let items = 0;  let price = 0;   cart.forEach((item) => {    items += item.qty;    price += item.qty * item.price;  });   setTotalItems(items);  setTotalPrice(price); },);`

Comment: I have assumed you are using react native.  ```<View>
      {cart.map((item, index) => (
        <View key={index}>
          <Text>{`Product Name: ${item.name}`}</Text>
          <Text>{`Size: ${item.size}`}</Text>
          <Text>{`Quantity: ${item.qty}`}</Text>
          <Text>{`Price: ${item.price}`}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
      <Text>{`Total Items: ${totalItems}`}</Text>
      <Text>{`Total Price: ${totalPrice}`}</Text>
    </View>```

Comment: Yes buddy, I'm using react native. However, all product details can show up in the cart except the selected size and the selected price? here the link of the updated code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77561034/add-same-product-with-different-sizes-and-prices-to-the-cart/77561231?noredirect=1#comment136838074_77561231  ? could you please have a look at it

Comment: @BashamlanSalem could you please elaborate the current problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just add some flag to maintain the selected price in `prices` array for each (either you can keep it all false or keep one size as default)

```
prices: [
    {size: 'S', price: '1.38', currency: '$', isSelected: false },
    {size: 'M', price: '3.15', currency: '$', isSelected: true },
    {size: 'L', price: '4.29', currency: '$', isSelected: false },
  ]
```

When user makes selection and click on add product to cart, you can pass the product to state with respective size's flag updated as true

```
  case 'ADD':
      const selectedPrice = action.payload.prices.find(sp => sp.isSelected)
      
      const productItem = products.find(
        (product) => product.id === action.payload.id
      );

      // Check if Item is in cart already
      const inCart = state.cart.find((item) => {
        const cartSelectedPrice = item.prices.find(sp => sp.isSelected);
       
        const sizeExists = selectedPrice && cartSelectedPrice && 
                           selectedPrice.size === cartSelectedPrice.size;

        return item.id === action.payload.id && sizeExists ? true : false
        }        
      );

       return {
           ...state,
           cart: inCart
              ? state.cart.map((item) =>
              item.id === action.payload.id
                 ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 }
                  : item
                 )
                 : [...state.cart, { ...productItem , qty: 1 }],
           };
```

Comment: Well, Your code is working  and thank you for that, But can you please show me how to display each product in the cart screen after adding with different selected size?  here is my cart screen code `const Cart=({navigation})=>{

  const {cart}= useCart();
 
 const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = React.useState(0);
 const [totalItems, setTotalItems] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
 let items = 0;
 let price = 0;

 cart.forEach((item) => {
   items += item.qty;
   price += item.qty * item.price;
 });

 setTotalItems(items);
 setTotalPrice(price);
},);

`